# Disable button if space is entered input box using prop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a function which disables button if button is blank but I would like to disable it if input have only spaces. below is my code but I am unable to understand how can I add that into my jquery code.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" maxlength="200" style="margin-left: 0;" name="Name" id="Name" value="" />
<button type="add" name="btnadd" class="actionButton" disabled="disabled">
            <span>Add Name</span></button>
```

**JS Script**

```
var validateName = function() {

         if ($('#Name').val() == '' || !$('#Name').val().trim().length){

            $('button.actionButton').prop('disabled', true);
          }
          else {
            $('button.actionButton').prop('disabled', false);
          }

    };

        $('#Name').keyup(function(e) {

            validateName();
        });

  $(document).ready(function(){

        validateName();
  });
```

Comment: Post your HTML too. We need a [mcve]

Comment: you need to add trim() method after $('#Name').val().trim(); to remove whitespace from both sides of a string

Comment: I did tried to add `if ($('#Name').val() == '' || $('#Name').val().trim()){` but that didn't work out for me is there any other option?

Comment: @j08691 updated my description based on your request

Comment: The code you entered is not pure javascript, it is jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use trim on the value to remove all trailing whitespace. That way you can always just check if it's empty.

```
If (!$("#Name").val().trim().length) {
  // disable button
}
```

Trim removes all whitespace at the start or end of your string. So you just need to check if the trimmed value has any length and it should handle empty values and values with only spaces.

---

### Update

If you want to disable the button anytime there's whitespace at the start of the input string, then you'll need a regular expression.

```
var val = $('#Name').val()

// this condition checks if there's whitespace at the beginning
// or if the string is empty
// if either is true we disable the button
if (/^\s/.test(val) || !val.trim().length) {
  // disable the button
}
```

With this new condition you don't need to check `val === ''`. That's handled by `!val.trim().length`.

Comment: I did tried to add `if ($('#Name').val() == '' || $('#Name').val().trim()){` but that didn't work out for me is there any other option?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't add the whole condition. Updated answer to reflect.

Comment: That works but if after few space, if text is entered button gets enabled. How can I solve that. I have updated my description to show how am I doing it.

Comment: If they enter in a non-whitespace character, then the input has a value, so the button should be enabled. Are you saying you want the button to be disabled if there's a space anywhere in the input value?

Comment: Not anywhere but atleast if space exist before the character example "                                   text"<--- in here there are whitespaces before text then button should also gets disabled.

Comment: Why? I'm not clear on the purpose of that use case. If you are concerned about saving values that have whitespace at the front or end of your string, just trim your values before submitting them.

Comment: I already add to my code to trim but while typing before text if space exist button should not get enable. Its kind of a requirement I have for this form.

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

**Try something like that with *.attr()***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true); // initially button is disabled
  $('#Name').on('keyup', function() {
    var text_value = $("#Name").val();
    if (!text_value.trim().length) {
      $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', false);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Name" type="text" name="name" />
<input type="submit" value="Next" />
```

**Other wise try something like that with *.prop()***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Name').on('keyup', function() {
    var text_value = $("#Name").val();
    if (!text_value.trim().length) {
      $('button.actionButton').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('button.actionButton').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.actionButton {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Name" type="text" name="name" />
<button class="actionButton" disabled>Next</button>
```

Comment: Works but if you enter few spaces then if you enter text button gets eneabled. How to solve that to ignore spaces in starting of text.

Answer (score 0):

A short regular expression can test if the input string contains anything other than whitespace.

```
if (/[^\s]/.test($('#Name').val()))
    $('button.actionButton').prop('disabled', false);
else
    $('button.actionButton').prop('disabled', true);
```

Or for a single line expression...

```
$('button.actionButton').prop('disabled', !(/[^\s]/.test($('#Name').val())));
```

Comment: Your first snippet is wrong when `/[^\s]/.test($('#Name').val()` button gets enabled rather then disable.